# How can I redirect the root and pages to different locations with htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I've moved an entire site from its own domain into my main site. I need to add a 301 to the old site. However, I need to root to go to one location but all of it's pages to go to another.

If my old site is `oldsite.com` I need it to go to `newsite.com/blog` and the sub pages like `oldsite.com/blog-post` to go to `newsite.com/blog-post`.

I did a full redirect on another site like this: `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newsite.com/$1 [R=301,L]` but that sends the root to `newsite.com`. This rule would work for moving the pages but not the pages as it seems.

To clarify:

`oldsite.com` → `newsite.com/blog`

`oldsite.com/blog-post` → `newsite.com/blog-post`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root page can be matched by the empty string `^$`, so you could employ two rules, one for the root

```
RewriteRule ^$ http://newsite.com/newroot [L]
```

and another rule for the rest of the pages

```
RewriteRule ^. http://newsite.com/blog%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

---

Another way to exclude the root is to use `.+` instead of `.*`, see [Apache - Regular Expressions](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html#regex) or [Regular Expression Reference: Quantifiers](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refrepeat.html) for details on the difference.